# why mysql nested select faster than join in my case?

Tags: mysql, join

**Hi Guys,**

**My problem below, i think the problem is my INNER JOIN snippet, how to  optimize?**

---

**Database relationship:**

[image]

**Query Condition:** sitename
**Query Target:** graph_path

#### SQL:

1. Inner Join:

   > **SELECT** *graph.graph_path* 
   >   **FROM** *sites* 
   >   **INNER JOIN** inventory on (sites.id = inventory.site_id) 
   >   **INNER JOIN** host on (host.inventory_id = inventory.id) 
   >   **INNER JOIN** graph on (graph.host_id = host.id) 
   >   **WHERE** sites.sitename = '10071';
   >   **Results:**
   >   1 rows in set (**2.74 sec**)
   >   **Explain:**
   >   [image]
2. Nested:

   > **SELECT** *graph_path*
   >   **FROM** *graph*
   >   **WHERE** host_id = (select id from host where inventory_id = (select id from inventory where site_id = (select id from sites where sitename = '10071')));
   >   **Results:**
   >   1 row in set (**0.03 sec**)
   >   **Explain:**
   >   [image]

Comment: show us the `explain` output of both

Comment: ok, i will show it later, thanks.

Comment: Did you run the two queries one after another without clearing query cache?

Comment: It looks as if host doesn't have an index on inventory_id *and/or* host.inventory_id is not the same data type as inventory.id.  Is either of those the case?  If so, the this is confusing the optimizer into choosing a bad plan on the first query, and the second query is respectable but still not as fast as it could be.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal indexes for this query are:  `sites(sitename, id)`, `inventory(site_id, id)`, `host(inventory, id)`, `graph(hostid, graph_path)`.

I am guessing that you only have indexes on the `id`s in the tables.  In the first version, it does all the joins first and then filters by site.  In the second, it probably scans `sites` first, and then progresses through the rest of the query quickly.

Comment: snippet like **SELECT * FROM sites(sitename, id) INNER JOIN blabla...** ?